# fill form fields from relationship model in vform vue laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have used vue vform for my form, here is the function to edit modal,

```
   editModal(household){
        this.form.reset();
        $('#addNewHouseholdModal').modal('show');
        this.form.fill(household); // this line fills the form with data to be edited
    }
```

But I have form fields for which data is stored in another table. I have received the data but mnot able to figure out how to display them in the form. Please help me with it. Below is the household data i have passed in my form above.

```
id: 1
address_details_id: 14
ward: 2
house_no: "2"
family_no: "45"
geolocation: "{"latitude":"1.1","longitude":"1.1"}"
address_details: Object
  id: 14
  province: "23"
  name: "Strret"
```

All details are filled in the form except Address details which is an object, how do I fill name from address details in the form? Thank you. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass first the data before you open the modal.

```
editModal(data) {
  isEditting = true
  this.form.family_no = data.family_no
  this.form.house_no = data.house_no
  this.form.address = data.address
  $('#addNewHouseholdModal').modal('show');
}
```

and then you form must be like this

```
<modal>
  <input type="text" v-model="form.family_no" />
  <input type="text" v-model="form.house_no" />
  <input type="text" v-model="form.address" />
<modal>
```